# payflow transparent redirect always taking to the error url

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

im trying to implement Paypal Payments Prop - transparent redirect.

Here are the steps that i perfom:

1) i send a request the payflow gateway i.e. `https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com` with some parameters like

```
SILENTTRAN=TRUE
CREATESECURETOKEN=Y
TRXTYPE=A
VERBOSITY=HIGH
TENDER=C
```

i get a proper response from the gateway.

for e.g.:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => RESULT=0
    [1] => SECURETOKEN=1eh4ht2k4kUatSIjfqs0qzA4k
    [2] => SECURETOKENID=ac31cb968d2902d4df3f10820f60f6fb
    [3] => RESPMSG=Approved
)
```

2) Now since i want to perform a transparent redirect i will post the creditcard details directly to the payflow gateway using this form

```
<form action='https://payflowlink.paypal.com/' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='MODE' value='TEST'>
<input type='hidden' name='SECURETOKEN' value='mysecuretoken'>
<input type='hidden' name='SECURETOKENID' value='mysecuretokenid'>
<label>Card Number</label> <input type='text' name='ACCT'>
<label>Code Code</label> <input type='text' name='CVV2'>
<label>Expiration</label> <input type='text' name='EXPDATE'>
<input type='submit' value='Make the transaction' />
</form>
```

but after posting this form im always being redirected to the ERRORURL that i specify in the first step.

what could be the probable mistake that im doing??

**SOLVED :**
there was nothing wrong in the code the mistake was done in testing. i was using my sandox account creditcard numbers to test but it doesn't work with sandbox accounts. you need to use the creditcard numbers mentioned in the integration document.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to this integration document, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#testing-transactions ?

If so, it doesn't solve my problem.